# Open Stack, attempting to launch instance: libvirtError: unsupported configuration: CPU specification not supported by hypervisor

Tags: amazon-ec2, openstack

I'm running Openstack for test/learning purposes at the moment on AWS EC2 servers, specifically the m3 flavor which features High Frequency Intel Xeon E5-2670 (Sandy Bridge) Processors.

Whenever I launch an instance I get this error in /var/log/nova/nova-compute.log

```
libvirtError: unsupported configuration: CPU specification not supported by hypervisor
```

The error is fairly self explanatory and I've found these links which point to a possible solution:

> https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/LibvirtXMLCPUModel
>
> https://www.berrange.com/posts/2010/02/15/guest-cpu-model-configuration-in-libvirt-with-qemukvm/

I've been going at it by (educated) trial and error but haven't been successful thus far and I'm afraid I just missed something obvious.

Am I on the right path? Would anyone who has run Openstack on AWS be able to share some insight?

**Edit**

Found this in my log file,

```
2014-04-30 01:56:05.986 1145 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver [req-be5f0c96-cdd7-4ac3-a526-24c77b76a121 4e1ab5ced4394c309396f4487f58c187 b51412721c1045bd93d6dd5e513a4bca] An error occurred while trying to launch a defined domain with xml: <domain type='qemu'>
  <name>instance-00000001</name>
  <uuid>4b5edb76-7e09-425f-a71f-5c7b48fe2ac7</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>524288</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>524288</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>1</vcpu>
  <sysinfo type='smbios'>
    <system>
      <entry name='manufacturer'>OpenStack Foundation</entry>
      <entry name='product'>OpenStack Nova</entry>
      <entry name='version'>2013.2.2</entry>
      <entry name='serial'>4aeceff8-3582-48be-8712-ac2febc819c3</entry>
      <entry name='uuid'>4b5edb76-7e09-425f-a71f-5c7b48fe2ac7</entry>
    </system>
  </sysinfo>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-1.5'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
    <smbios mode='sysinfo'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='host-model'>
    <model fallback='allow'/>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='utc'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2' cache='none'/>
      <source file='/var/lib/nova/instances/4b5edb76-7e09-425f-a71f-5c7b48fe2ac7/disk'/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'/>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='fa:16:3e:0b:9b:b8'/>
      <source bridge='br100'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <driver name='qemu'/>
      <filterref filter='nova-instance-instance-00000001-fa163e0b9bb8'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='file'>
      <source path='/var/lib/nova/instances/4b5edb76-7e09-425f-a71f-5c7b48fe2ac7/console.log'/>
      <target port='0'/>
    </serial>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <target port='1'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='file'>
      <source path='/var/lib/nova/instances/4b5edb76-7e09-425f-a71f-5c7b48fe2ac7/console.log'/>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
    </console>
    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'/>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport='yes' listen='localhost' keymap='en-us'>
      <listen type='address' address='localhost'/>
    </graphics>
    <video>
      <model type='cirrus' vram='9216' heads='1'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>

2014-04-30 01:56:05.987 1145 ERROR nova.compute.manager [req-be5f0c96-cdd7-4ac3-a526-24c77b76a121 4e1ab5ced4394c309396f4487f58c187 b51412721c1045bd93d6dd5e513a4bca] [instance: 4b5edb76-7e09-425f-a71f-5c7b48fe2ac7] Instance failed to spawn
2014-04-30 01:56:05.987 1145 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 4b5edb76-7e09-425f-a71f-5c7b48fe2ac7] Traceback (most recent call last):
2014-04-30 01:56:05.987 1145 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 4b5edb76-7e09-425f-a71f-5c7b48fe2ac7]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1423, in _spawn
2014-04-30 01:56:05.987 1145 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 4b5edb76-7e09-425f-a71f-5c7b48fe2ac7]     block_device_info)
2014-04-30 01:56:05.987 1145 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 4b5edb76-7e09-425f-a71f-5c7b48fe2ac7]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 2091, in spawn
2014-04-30 01:56:05.987 1145 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 4b5edb76-7e09-425f-a71f-5c7b48fe2ac7]     block_device_info, context=context)
2014-04-30 01:56:05.987 1145 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 4b5edb76-7e09-425f-a71f-5c7b48fe2ac7]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 3249, in _create_domain_and_network
2014-04-30 01:56:05.987 1145 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 4b5edb76-7e09-425f-a71f-5c7b48fe2ac7]     domain = self._create_domain(xml, instance=instance, power_on=power_on)
2014-04-30 01:56:05.987 1145 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 4b5edb76-7e09-425f-a71f-5c7b48fe2ac7]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 3192, in _create_domain
2014-04-30 01:56:05.987 1145 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 4b5edb76-7e09-425f-a71f-5c7b48fe2ac7]     domain.XMLDesc(0))
2014-04-30 01:56:05.987 1145 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 4b5edb76-7e09-425f-a71f-5c7b48fe2ac7]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 3187, in _create_domain
2014-04-30 01:56:05.987 1145 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 4b5edb76-7e09-425f-a71f-5c7b48fe2ac7]     domain.createWithFlags(launch_flags)
2014-04-30 01:56:05.987 1145 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 4b5edb76-7e09-425f-a71f-5c7b48fe2ac7]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 179, in doit
2014-04-30 01:56:05.987 1145 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 4b5edb76-7e09-425f-a71f-5c7b48fe2ac7]     result = proxy_call(self._autowrap, f, *args, **kwargs)
2014-04-30 01:56:05.987 1145 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 4b5edb76-7e09-425f-a71f-5c7b48fe2ac7]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 139, in proxy_call
2014-04-30 01:56:05.987 1145 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 4b5edb76-7e09-425f-a71f-5c7b48fe2ac7]     rv = execute(f,*args,**kwargs)
2014-04-30 01:56:05.987 1145 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 4b5edb76-7e09-425f-a71f-5c7b48fe2ac7]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 77, in tworker
2014-04-30 01:56:05.987 1145 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 4b5edb76-7e09-425f-a71f-5c7b48fe2ac7]     rv = meth(*args,**kwargs)
2014-04-30 01:56:05.987 1145 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 4b5edb76-7e09-425f-a71f-5c7b48fe2ac7]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 728, in createWithFlags
2014-04-30 01:56:05.987 1145 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 4b5edb76-7e09-425f-a71f-5c7b48fe2ac7]     if ret == -1: raise libvirtError ('virDomainCreateWithFlags() failed', dom=self)
2014-04-30 01:56:05.987 1145 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 4b5edb76-7e09-425f-a71f-5c7b48fe2ac7] libvirtError: unsupported configuration: CPU specification not supported by hypervisor
2014-04-30 01:56:05.987 1145 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 4b5edb76-7e09-425f-a71f-5c7b48fe2ac7] 
2014-04-30 01:56:06.950 1145 ERROR nova.compute.manager [req-be5f0c96-cdd7-4ac3-a526-24c77b76a121 4e1ab5ced4394c309396f4487f58c187 b51412721c1045bd93d6dd5e513a4bca] [instance: 4b5edb76-7e09-425f-a71f-5c7b48fe2ac7] Error: unsupported configuration: CPU specification not supported by hypervisor
```

Comment: I don't know anything about OpenStack, so I could be completely wrong, but just in case: are you sure that you can run OpenStack's hypervisor on AWS instances? I understand that you can create the "ecosystem" that OpenStack needs (the support servers), but creating virtual machines on the top of another virtual machine seems a bit far-fetched. Though I'd love to be corrected.

Comment: That's a good point. I'm fairly certain that I did manage to get Opesntack instances to run within a virtualized environment at some point though. Either within VirtualBox or on EC2 servers but quite some time ago so my memory is hazy. From what I understand [qemu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/QemuEmulator) makes this all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I misread this [resource](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/ReleaseNotes/Folsom) regarding known issues the first time around. It says the following:

> The default value for the libvirt_cpu_mode option is "host-model" but
>   apparently this results in an error like "unsupported configuration:
>   CPU specification not supported by hypervisor" if you run Nova inside
>   a VM; libvirt_cpu_mode="none" should be used for such deployments
>   http://wiki.openstack.org/LibvirtXMLCPUModel

So if you're facing this issue be sure to specify

```
libvirt_cpu_mode="none"
```

in /etc/nova/nova.conf

Answer (score 1):

As Jack suggested, I think you are trying to host a KVM box instead of qemu. KVM is not supported by AWS, so you'll need to switch to qemu. Please check point #7 at http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/install-guide/install/apt/content/nova-compute.html

From the guide:
If you install Compute on a virtual machine for testing purposes, you must determine whether your hypervisor and/or CPU support nested hardware acceleration using the following command:

```
egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
```

If this command returns a value of one or greater, your hypervisor and/or CPU support nested hardware acceleration which requires no additional configuration.

If this command returns a value of zero, your hypervisor and/or CPU do not support nested hardware acceleration and libvirt must use QEMU instead of KVM. Edit the [libvirt] section in the /etc/nova/nova-compute.conf file to modify this key:

```
[libvirt]
...
virt_type = qemu
```

Comment: Can you add a description of what "point 7" is in case the link goes bad?

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, unfortunately I'm still getting the same message regarding the cpu type. In my nova-compute.conf the entry is already listed as "libvirt_type=qemu" (not "virt_type=qemu"), I've tried both just to be safe but no luck. Also, in my /etc/nova/nova.conf this can be found, "libvirt_cpu_mode=host-model
libvirt_type=qemu"